# Time taken to run for loop

Tags: r

I am new to R and I have following query.
I am trying to run a following for  loop. It took 20 minutes to run on 30,000 rows. I want to run on 4 million rows. I tried and it is taking almost 3 days. Is there any way to minimize the time taken to run the loop.

```
for(i in length(Data$CLAIM):1)
{
  if(i==length(Data$CLAIM))
  {
    Data$Net_Claim_Amt_Calc[i]=Data$INETCLMAMT[i]
    Data$GOL_Calc[i]=Data$GOL[i]
    Data$GLP_Calc[i]=Data$GLP[i]
    Data$NOLCLM_Calc[i]=Data$NOLCLM[i]
    Data$NLPCLM_Calc[i]=Data$NLPCLM[i]
  }
  else 
  {
    if(Data$CLAIM[i]==Data$CLAIM[i+1])

    {
      Data$Net_Claim_Amt_Calc[i]=sum(Data$INETCLMAMT[i],Data$Net_Claim_Amt_Calc[i+1])
      Data$GOL_Calc[i]=Data$GOL[i]+Data$GOL_Calc[i+1]
      Data$GLP_Calc[i]=Data$GLP[i]+Data$GLP_Calc[i+1]
      Data$NOLCLM_Calc[i]=Data$NOLCLM[i]+Data$NOLCLM_Calc[i+1]
      Data$NLPCLM_Calc[i]=Data$NLPCLM[i]+Data$NLPCLM_Calc[i+1]
    }
    else
    {
      Data$Net_Claim_Amt_Calc[i]=Data$INETCLMAMT[i]
      Data$GOL_Calc[i]=Data$GOL[i]
      Data$GLP_Calc[i]=Data$GLP[i]
      Data$NOLCLM_Calc[i]=Data$NOLCLM[i]
      Data$NLPCLM_Calc[i]=Data$NLPCLM[i]
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: are you sure you cant vectorize?

Comment: This doesn't look like you should use a `for` loop. (A `for` loop with 4e6 iterations is pretty much always a bad idea in R. There usually are faster (vectorized) alternatives.)

Comment: I have never used vectorized before. can you guide me in providing some links related to vectorized format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen the data.

You can try the following instead of comparing element by element.

Eg . the data (random values) ,

```
  Claim INETCLMAMT
1   100          0
2   100        100
3    50         50
4    45         21
5    52         64
6    52         56
7     4         37
8    38          6
9    45         29
```

Instead of comparing each element individually, you can apply the comparison to the whole column. For instance,

```
 data$Claim == data$Claim
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

In your case, you are comparing one `i th` element to the `i+1` element. So we can create a new column which contains the `i+1` value.

```
data$Claim_next = c(data$Claim[-1],0)

data$Claim == data$Claim_next
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

This returns `TRUE` for rows 1 and 5 , since the next rows have the same values.

Now you can perform your comparison,

```
if (data$Claim == data$Claim_next){
  Data$Net_Claim_Amt_Calc=Data$INETCLMAMT #replace with the actual code
}
```

This `if` check will assign the value to `INETCLMANT` to `Net_Claim_Amt_Calc` if the `i th` value of `Claim` is the same as the `i+1` value.

Similarly, assignment need not be done element wise.

```
Data$Net_Claim_Amt_Calc=Data$INETCLMAMT
```

or

```
Data$Net_Claim_Amt_Calc = sum(some columns)
```

Comment: Problem is, It will not do it on run-time basis. 
e.g. if the CLAIM number in row 9 and row 10 is same, then in row it should sum Net_Claim_Amt_Calc[10] and INETCLMANT[9]. However, this will require Net_Claim_Amt_Calc[10]  to be updated before we update row 9.

Let me know if this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This code can be easily vectorised.

A simple data set to get started:

```
claims= sample(1:3, 10, replace=T)
```

Using the `diff` function we can determine where we have consecutive values

```
d = diff(claims)
equals = which(d==0)
```

You code is now something like:

```
## Standard
Data$Net_Claim_Amt_Calc[i]=Data$INETCLMAMT[i]
Data$GOL_Calc[i]=Data$GOL[i]
Data$GLP_Calc[i]=Data$GLP[i]
Data$NOLCLM_Calc[i]=Data$NOLCLM[i]
Data$NLPCLM_Calc[i]=Data$NLPCLM[i]
```

Where values are equal

```
i = equals
Data$Net_Claim_Amt_Calc[i]= sum(Data$INETCLMAMT[i],Data$Net_Claim_Amt_Calc[i+1])
Data$GOL_Calc[i]=Data$GOL[i]+Data$GOL_Calc[i+1]
Data$GLP_Calc[i]=Data$GLP[i]+Data$GLP_Calc[i+1]
Data$NOLCLM_Calc[i]=Data$NOLCLM[i]+Data$NOLCLM_Calc[i+1]
Data$NLPCLM_Calc[i]=Data$NLPCLM[i]+Data$NLPCLM_Calc[i+1]
```